# Javascript scope problem

Tags: javascript, scope

I am calling this function, assigning the result to a variable in the callback and then logging the result, but I keep getting undefined.

```
var id;
test.getID(function(result) {
    id=result;
});
console.log(id);
```

If I change it to the code below, then I can see the id logged.

```
var id;
test.getID(function(result) {
    id=result;   
    console.log(id);
});
```

Do you know what I can do to be able to access the result of the getID function?

Comment: it's probably because you're logging `id` immediately. The callback you're passing to `getID` is probably getting executed *after* your `console.log`. That's why the second one works...you're logging it after the callback has done it's work.

Comment: It's not about scope, it's about "timing", I guess that `test.getID` is doing something asynchronous, and when you try  to log the value of `id`, it hasn't yet been assigned... Work on the callback, or call a separate function, passing your `result`...

Comment: Does `test.getID` make an Ajax request?

Comment: I think test.getID might be making an Ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getID` function will need to invoke its parameter before you will see `id` change.

Since you do not provide its implementation, let's assume it's something like this. Pay close attention to the implementation of `getID`, it takes a function as the parameter, `f`, and then invokes it. This is when `id` will be set.

```
var id;
var test = { 
    getID: function(f){
        var result = 666; //assume result comes from somewhere
        f(result); //Note: this is where your function is getting invoked.
    }
};

test.getID(function(result) {
    id = result;
});

console.log(id); //prints 666
```

Answer (score 0):

A [**closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) would work for you as well:

```
var id,
test = {
  getID: function (id) {
    this.id = id;
  },
  id: -1
};

test.getID((function(result) {
    id=result;
    return id;
})(78));
console.log(id);
```